# Disable auto-open for a specific device

Tags: linux, gnome, usb-flash-drive, nautilus, ubuntu-11.10

When I insert a flash drive, always is opened a new window of nautilus showing the content of the flash drive. Is there a form to deactivate "auto-open" option for a determinate USB device?

Thanks!